# Android proguard same jar specified twice

Tags: android, proguard

I have a project with two dependency projects in the libraries folder. Both are libraries which i wrote.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardgmobileRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: The same input jar [/Users/Jon/android-app-manager/app/libs/**] is specified twice.

The main project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile project(':android-commons')
    compile project(':ormlitewrapper')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

The android-commons project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
}
```

The OrmLiteWrapper project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile project(':android-commons')
}
```

The main project compiles the 2 sub project and ormLiteWrapper compiles the android-commons as well. I was unable to remove the dependency and don't know where I can find the solution for the cyclic dependency. Should it be defined in one place and referenced in the other?
The issue only creates a conflict when generating a release APK.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `-libraryjars` or `-injar` or `-oujar` in your proguard file

Comment: Ok, but what do I have to use instead of -libraryjars or -injar or -oujar to say proguard skip .jar file?

Comment: You can use keep command to all classes in your jar file. For example use: '-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }' for skip android-support-v4.jar (see your structure of packages inside jar)